# Progress Bar problem

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have a button that onclick reads and shows to the user a list with rss news.  I would like to add a progress bar until finish loading.  My problem is that, if I add a bar, it works properly at first but if I press the back button, the bar starts again and it can't stop.  Any help or a tutorial that demonstrates a progressbar would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
ProgressBar myProgressBar;
  int myProgress = 0;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.main1);

  Button nea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nea);
   nea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick (View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.bar);

     myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.bar);

           new Thread(myThread).start();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nea.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }  
  });
}

private Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){    
    @Override
    public void run() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     while (myProgress<100){
      try{
       myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
       Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
      catch(Throwable t){
      }
     }
    }

    Handler myHandle = new Handler(){

     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      myProgress++;
      myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
     }
    };
      };
```

Comment: show some code please, it hard to say smthing without it.

Comment: remove the progress bar  when the data loding is complete

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do with a progress bar?  Your current implementation appears that it is doing nothing.

Comment: i want to have a progress bar until the rss load and then dismiss the bar,so when the user returns to main screen with my buttons, i dont want to see the bar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'd implement this with an `AsyncTask`, where you start the progress bar in `onPreExecute()`, cancel it in `onPostExecute()` and do the downloading in `doInBackground()`. If you want to update the progress value, you can `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()` which can then be updated on the ProgressBar in `onProgressUpdate()`

https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java#L328 
shows how an example of an AsyncTask that uses those methods and which shows / hides a progress bar ( `pg` variable )

Comment: Updated my answer to link to an example

Comment: could you  pleake make your answer more spesific...i m new in android dev and i get confused with this big tutorial...anyway thanks for your try

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't restore the myProgress variable. Set it to 0 in the beginning of onCreate():

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.main1);
  myProgress = 0; // <--- notice that statement.
  ...
 }
```

Also, I would propose you to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for any background work. See example [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Comment: ProgressBar myProgressBar=0; ?

Comment: could you please help me with your async task example..?

Comment: Try implementing and when you have troubles just ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look like it is working as you want it to.  You would like to display a progress bar between this Activity and the next (my assumption).  Based on how your code is working now, it looks as though the current activity will start a thread that will display a progress bar for about 100 seconds, but at the same time you are loading your second Activity.  So if before the 100 seconds is up, if you hit the back button, you will go back to the original Activity, which is still showing the progress bar.

Generally, I do not think that you need a progress bar between Activities though, as they should swap between them pretty smoothly.  I would typically use a progress bar to load data before an Activity can be fully rendered.

Maybe you should take a look at some of the Android documentation on ProgressBar's:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem here, i use a indeterminate progress bar  before launching a thread and eventually i go to another activity where it still shows the progressbar if the theread is still doing something and eventually it does stop on the second activity, but if i go back teh progressbar still shows....
i use static methods for getting and setting the ProgressBar state...

Comment: also i tried changing the state of the progress bar in the onResume that is launched when you press back button but it still shows the progressbar spinning...:S

Comment: @Maxrunner:  If you have a question, you should ask a new one.